# Evaluate many functions using one data in R

Tags: r, function, apply, evaluate, sapply

I know that I can evaluate one function with many data using apply, but can I evaluate many functions using one data? 
Using sapply i can get:

```
sapply(list(1:5,10:20,5:18), sum)
```

but I want somethnig like this:

```
sapply(1:5, list(sum, min,max))
```

and get

```
15 1 5
```

Any clever idea? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swap the argument order, since you are looping over the functions not the data.

```
sapply(list(sum, min, max), function(f) f(1:5))
```

---

The two most preferred modern approaches for calculating summary statistics use the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages.  `dplyr` has a variety of solutions (only working with data frames, not vectors) using [`summarise`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/dplyr/docs/summarise) or `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
summarise(data, min = min(x), max = max(x), sum = sum(x))
summarise_each(data, funs(min, max, sum))
```

The `dplyr`-idiomatic style is to construct expressions using [chaining](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/dplyr/docs/chain).

```
data %>%
 summarise(min = min(x), max = max(x), sum = sum(x))
data %>%
  summarise_each(funs(min, max, sum))
```

For programmatic use (as opposed to interactive use), underscore-suffixed functions and [formulae](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/formula) are recommended for [non-standard evaluation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

```
data %>%
 summarise_(min = ~ min(x), max = ~ max(x), sum = ~ sum(x))
data %>%
  summarise_each_(funs_(c("min", "max", "sum"), "x")
```

---

See [agstudy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17720721/134830) for the `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can evaluate many functions on many data. Just use an anonymous function like this:

```
sapply( list(1:5,10:20,5:18), function(x) c( Sum = sum(x) , Min = min(x) , Max = max(x) ) )
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#Sum   15  165  161
#Min    1   10    5
#Max    5   20   18
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `summarize` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
summarize(data.frame(x=1:5),min=min(x),max=max(x),sum=sum(x))
  min max sum
1   1   5  15
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x=1:5)[,list(min=min(x),max=max(x),sum=sum(x))]
  min max sum
1:   1   5  15
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another we can add to the pot.  Nice for working with large lists.

```
funs <- list(sum = sum, min = min, max = max)
Map(function(f, ...) f(...),  funs, list(x = 1:15))
# $sum
# [1] 120
#
# $min
# [1] 1
#
# $max
# [1] 15
```